simultaneously connect to two databases in python for a query that depends on the two databases oracle sql
I want to simultaneously connect to two databases in python for a query that depends on the two databases in oracle sql developer
The example is following :
SELECT t1.id_client, t1.sales, t2.cost
FROM table_1@database_1 t1
JOIN table_2@database_2 t2
ON t1.id_client = t2.id_client

table 1 is from database_1
table 2 is from database_2
thanks!
I tried using cx_Oracle in python but it didnt work, it only connects to one of the databases.

Does both of them in same server?

While you could do this in your client, you can probably do it more easily simply by using a dblink and letting the databases talk. Then you only need to manage one connection from your client.

To be clear, SQL runs in the database, not the client, so you couldn't have a single SQL command that would query two separate physical databases on two separate connections simultaneously. As Paul W mentioned, you would need to connect the two databases with a DB link and then execute the query just in the first database using one client connection.

(i) The table_1@database_1 syntax is a DB link usage, so this should work fine in Python like it does in SQLDeveloper since SQL is executed in the database, not the driver/tool side (ii) don't forget to schedule your upgrade to the latest version of cx_Oracle, which was released under the new name python-oracledb a couple of years ago, see the release announcement.
